# Take a picture and reduce the quality

Tags: android

In my Android app, I have a button to take a picture like this :

```
button_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fname_" +
                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

and in my ActivityResult :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadPicture.class);
            intent.putExtra("URI", imageUri.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
```

I would like to reduce the quality of my picture (I want a picture lighter for the server) before starting the activity of upload.
How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: quality? why? I would rather resize the image (if you don't need good quality then it means that also you don't need resolution larger then  1MP (1280 x 960))

Answer (score 2):

Convert the image into `Bitmap` before uploading and compress the bitmap set the quality of the image and write it to the correct path.The quality of the image can be changed and hope this will help you to reduce the size of the image.

`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);`

`compress` method is defined as

`public boolean compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)`

You can take help from this also [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: Thanks! But what is **OutputStream stream** parametre ?

Comment: See example 7 in this [code](http://www.javased.com/?api=android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat)